# Communicating between a php web server and a C# desktop application

Tags: c#, php, sockets, real-time

I have a web service with `php` which is listening to some other services and receive some messages. After getting the message I want to deliver it to my desktop application.

I don't want that my desktop app call my web service to see the message, instead I want to push my message to desktop app.

In `C#` we can listen to pipe when it changes. But don't have any idea how to deal with it in php. Or maybe I use `socket` between desktop app and web service.

Any idea would highly appreciated.

Comment: Use a websocket or [server-sent-event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks. Is there any library for both `php` and `c#` ?

Comment: In C# (client) [websocket-sharp](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp#websocket-client) and in PHP (server) [Workerman](https://github.com/walkor/Workerman) or [ReactPHP](https://github.com/reactphp/socket) - you wont find a lib cross lang, but for the most part look for ones which adear to the protocol

Comment: You need to use standard input (or standard output).  See : http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php  In c# they are Console.Write() and Console.Read()

Comment: @jdweng How should I deliver the message to C# application? How should they connect to each other?

Comment: The command line will connect output from one app to input to other app using a pipe.

Comment: I'd say a socket or named pipe or intermediary service like a message queue (the latter being likely the most robust way).